# org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, httpconnection

I am getting the following error when i am trying to connect to a url https://jazz.net on worklight 5.0.6..

> Procedure invocation error. Runtime: Http request failed:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to
>   https://jazz.net refused

This is the response I am getting in log:

> {"responseID":"6","errors":["Runtime: Http request failed:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to
>   https://jazz.net
>   refused"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/

Here is the adapter xml code:

```
  <connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <domain>jazz.net</domain>
</connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
</connectivity>
```

Comment: Try adding also a port child-element with the value 443.

Comment: I have made it into Answer. Thanks. Please mark as 'answered' when possible if your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also add a child-element `port` with the value `443`.